# How can I get the actual size of a C1TrueDBGrid control in ComponentOne?

Tags: c#, componentone

I'm working with ComponentOne's Controls and I have a `C1TrueDBGrid`. I am trying to call the `DrawToBitmap` method:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(myGrid.Width, myGrid.Height);
Rectangle drawingBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, myGrid.Width, myGrid.Height);

myGrid.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap, drawingBounds);
```

However, because the `C1TrueDBGrid` scrolls, the `Width` and `Height` properties are likely to be smaller than the "actual" `Width` and `Height`. I looked through the property values `myGrid` while in debug mode trying to find anything that looked like what I would expact the "actual" `Width` and `Height` values to be, but with no luck.

Am I missing something? How can I get the "actual" size of a `C1TrueDBGrid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an unfortunate answer from the ComponentOne support forums, [one of the support reps said](http://our.componentone.com/groups/winforms/true-dbgrid-for-winforms/forum/topic/drawtobitmap-for-actual-size-of-c1truedbgrid/):

> IMHO, this is not possible. AFAIK, image can be captured within certain dimensions, and of something that’s visible. If I hide a row, even within visible range of the grid, and then using DrawToBitmap doesn’t capture the invisible row.